# Sorting a dictionary by int(value)

Tags: python, dictionary

`students_grade` is a list that contains tuples, each having a student name and a grade, both in a string.
For example:

```
students_grade = [('jon','88'), ('bran', '100'), ('arya','93'), ('dan', '88')]
```

The goal is to create a new list with the same tuples ordered by the grades:

```
[('jon','88'), ('dan', '88',' ('arya','93'),('bran','100')]
```

Tried solving it using a dictionary, however I noticed that `'100' < '93'` returns `True`, so I tried sorting the dictionary by `int(values)`, however got `TypeError`.

```
dic = {}
for i in students_grades:
    dic[i[0]] = i[1]
sorted_keys = sorted(dic.keys(), key = int(dic.get), reverse=True)
```

without the `int(dic.get)` it works fine. Why does it fail?

Comment: Because you're trying to convert a dictionary instance method to an integer. Presumably you meant something like `key = lambda k: int(dic.get(k))`. The `key` argument must be a callable that accepts a single argument.

Answer (score 1):

There's no concept of order for a normal dictionary, and anyway you don't need it for sorting the list. Try this:

```
x = [('jon', '88'), ('bran', '100'), ('arya', '93'), ('dan', '88')]
sorted(x, key=lambda pair: int(pair[1]))
=>  [('jon', '88'), ('dan', '88'), ('arya', '93'), ('bran', '100')]
```